# Reading data from MySQL Database to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-studio

I'm following this tutorial on youtube on how to read data using a json format from mysql database to android app. The app should display the json format of the table from the database whenever "get json" button is clicked. I carefully followed and reviewed the code and the php file but instead of a json format of my table that is to show on my textview, it turned out to be html code of something I don't know.

Here is my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String json_string ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void getJSON(View view)

{

    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}


class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
    String JSON_STRING;
    String json_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        json_url = "http://www.puc.gava.ph/get_data.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");


            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String result){
       TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
       textView.setText(result);
       json_string=result;


   }


}
```

}

I haven't yet done the parsing one because I want to do it step by step. 
Here is my get_data.php

```
<?php

$host= "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$db = "accounts";

$sql = "select * from user_info";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("username" => $row[0],"password" => $row[1],"email" =>  $row[2]));

}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

my php file is ok because I tested the link to the browser and it showed the json format of my table.

Here is somewhat what I receive in my textview

```
<br/>
  <b>Notice</b>:Undefined index:
  HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in <n>/var/www/ph/rd/functions.php<b>49</b></br/>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css"href=...........and so on.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's no code to support what you receive in textview. Show us what's inside `functions.php`.

Comment: I don't understand sir. What do you mean? I've seen other user with the same code as mine but his problem was only on the parsing and the viewing of json format was ok.

Comment: But I don't have any "functions.php" in my directory. btw I'm usin WAMP.

Comment: `<b>Notice</b>:Undefined index:
  HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in <n>/var/www/ph/rd/functions.php<b>49</b></br/>` what's that then? The error doesn't lie. Something is fetching that file.

Comment: that "Something is fetching that file" made me feel scared. hahaha. But seriously sir, I search that function.php file but I can't find it.

Comment: You need to search in your files on your own pc with "containing" function.php - might be something in `.htaccess` also, it's really hard to say.

Comment: Just one tip, if you want to work with Json in Android use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) from Square, it's literally the best way to work with Json and WebServices, AsyncTask and networking are a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can set the missing header in your java code:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US");
```

The browsers sets this header for you.

Comment: it removed only the upper html code before <html> but the output is still the same. but still thank you sir.